# LINQ - Need to find ID of existing or created record

Tags: linq

The query below check to see if a Folder record exist. If not, it creates a new record. Note that the Folder table has a primary key called ID that is an auto incremented. I need to find out what the ID was of the record that was created or already existed.  Need an efficient way of doing it. Currently I do am doing a long about way to find it.

```
// Checks to see if record exist
 var record = (from pl in db.Folders
               where pl.FolderSystem == "OP"
               && pl.OrgID == orgID
               select pl).FirstOrDefault();

// If does not exist create the record
 if (record == null)
 {
   db.Folders.Add(
             new Folders
             {
                 OrgID = orgID,
                 FolderSystem = "OP",                    
                 CreatedUserID = 1,
                 CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
              });

             db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Now I need to find the ID of the record that existed or needed to be created.  Need Folder.ID. Is there a more efficient way to find it. I am open to restructuring the query.

Comment: Is `OrgID` an identity column? If so, why do you care about creating it? (aside form the fact that doing that for an identity column using EF is *really* awkward...)

Comment: OrgID is not an identity column. It is merely the ID of the Organization. The identity column is called ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saveChanges, Id will be updated in your model:

```
 if (record == null) 
 {
     var record =
         new Folders
         {
             OrgID = orgID,
             FolderSystem = "OP",                    
             CreatedUserID = 1,
             CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
          });
     db.Folders.Add(record);

     db.SaveChanges(); 
 } 
 record.Id is the id
```

Answer (score 0):

If in *any* scenario you only want to know whether a record exists you don't have to pull the entire entity from the database:

```
var exists = db.Folders.Any(f => f.FolderSystem == "OP"
                              && f.OrgID == orgID);
```

This executes a cheap `EXISTS` query and returns a `boolean`.  About as light-weight as it gets.

If you want to know the ID of the existing record (for some reason) there is another light-weight pattern:

```
var id = db.Folders.Where(f => f.FolderSystem == "OP"
                            && f.OrgID == orgID)
                   .Select(f => f.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

This only queries one integer value (or null) from the database, still not the entire entity.

Now you can proceed by:

```
if(!id.HasValue)
{
    // Use an explicit variable for the new entity
    var record = new Folders
         {
             OrgID = orgID,
             FolderSystem = "OP",                    
             CreatedUserID = 1,
             CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
          });
    db.Folders.Add(record);
    db.SaveChanges();
    id = record.ID;
}
```

So `id` will either be the retrieved (existing) value or the new value.

Note that in your case you're not out of the woods yet. There's always a chance that right between the first query and your insert a second user inserts the same id. You always have to catch unique constraint exceptions.